# How do i hide columns containing zeros all through from rdlc report

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, rdlc

i am trying to hide rdlc report columns whose values are zeros all through, that is, if some cells have values within the column, it shouldn't hide using the column visibility property. this is my code:

```
 =iif(Fields!HousingAllowance.Value > 0,false,true)
```

this seems to work, but there is an issue with the above formula, it hides column if the first cell value for the column is zero, even when the column contains others values, i also tried this:

```
 =SUM(iif(Fields!HousingAllowance.Value > 0,false,true))
```

but no success, i want to be able to sum the column values, if the result is zero, it should hide, else it show.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the Max and Min functions in conjunction to determine weather all the values are 0 like this:

`=Max(Fields!HousingAllowance.Value + 0) = 0 And Min(Fields!HousingAllowance.Value + 0) = 0`

I used `+ 0` to convert null values to 0.